# Inject a variable into an Angular Controller from a Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Updating as there is some confusion as to what I am asking.  I would like to use a directive to inject a variable into the controller used by that directive.  I realize I can use the $scope for that, but I don't find that an intuitive solution.

---

Essentially I want my controller to have the proposal variable injected into it.

My intended usage:

```
<blah-directive proposal="proposal"></blah-directive>
```

The directive (so far):

```
app.directive('blahDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        , transclude: true
        , replace: true
        , scope: {
            proposal: '='
        }
        , templateUrl: 'blahTemp.html'
        , controller: blahController
    };
});
```

blahTemp.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="myBidForm">
    **{{ proposal }}**    
</form>
```

this is displaying the value proposal variable in the $scope fine, but it is not what I want.  Essentially I would like to define my controller like:

```
var blahController = function($scope, SomeOtherResource, proposal) {


}
```

Comment: Why do you want to inject te directive? Your directive makes the directive available in the scope. Just use $scope.proposal = ..

Comment: Y - I don't think that solution is obvious solution on the Controller side.  If someone picks up the controller they may not read the documentation and no idea how that variable got into scope.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. The scope that's being injected to your controller is the isolated scope (because it's the directive's controller) so why are you making a two-way-data-binding to the parent scope?

Comment: If someone just picks your controller without reading the documentation and without knowing anything about how angular works then He deserves the worse bugs.

Comment: Ilhan that last comment is not super constructive.  I am aim for my code  to be inutitive

Comment: When you create a directive with isolated scope and that directive has a controller, they should probably be coupled. They already share the same $element/$transclude/$scope/$attrs. If you want **proposal** to be injected everywhere you **must** define it as a provider(service).

Comment: It's not that it's unintuitive, you appear to be trying to do something that directives aren't meant to do, or are resisting using the `$scope` in the way it is there for you.  @IlanFrumer's suggestion makes the most sense.

Comment: @Shah I don't understand the use case so what would I suggest ?! All I can say is that $compile injects few additional locals to the directive's controller and you cannot change it (unless you declare a service).

Comment: Thanks Ilhan/Shah let direct my research.  Per the use case, I would only want it injected in this controller, not everywhere.  Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to inject locals into a controller use [$controller](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24controller).

Here is an example ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xcYfIhwNfdAg6wDHbREC?p=preview)):

```
app.directive('blahDirective', function ($controller) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      proposal : "="
    },
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'blahTemp.html',
    link : function (scope, elm, attrs){
      scope.proposal = {};
      var locals = {
        $scope: scope , 
        proposal: scope.proposal
      };
      $controller('blahController', locals);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: That looks to be what I was seeking. I am getting an "unknown provider proposalProvider" so I think I have typed something wrong.  I know it is on my end - the plunkr makes sense and works-  so I need to dig into what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Check your locals object